# How to get iframe onload event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reportviewer2008

I am using Reportviewer to view SSRS reports on my .aspx page.
Since this reportviewer is renders as iframe in the browser.
    I want call some javascript function every time iframe gets loaded.

```
 I can't use window.onload because the content of reportviewer that is iframes get changed without any postback.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will help since I've never used ReportViewer but if you have access to the server side page then do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MainIFrame.Attributes.Add("onload", "MainIFrame_OnLoad();");
    }
}
```

On your javascript file add the following:

```
function MainIFrame_OnLoad() {
    alert('yes!');
}
```